# php или jquery как проверить что в строке только буквы и цифры , то есть нету ;№ $&&* и дт

Tags: php, jquery

php или jq как проверить что в строке только буквы и цифры , то есть нету ;№ $&&* и дт

```
if(strlen($name) < 4){  
    $error_fields[] = 'name';
}

if(strlen($msg) < 10){
    $error_fields[] = 'msg';
}
```

как у $name и $msg проверить что в строке только буквы и цифры через php или jquery

Comment: регулярные выражения вам в помощь `/^[a-z\d]+$/i`

Comment: @InDevX это будет `123qwe` но не `qwe123`. при этом сам `\w` уже включает `\d`, а из лишнего включает `_`. Впрочем вероятно автора заинтересует не только латиница

Comment: @teran не тем местом подумал, видать) если без _ то алфавит указывать в регулярке или можно как-то так `"1213qwe".match(/\W+|_/) === null`